# Inclusion Exlusion Problems: twins and circular arrangements

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I had two combinatorics questions that I was having trouble **with using inclusion-exclusion methods to solve them**:

> 1. Given six pairs of non-identical twins, how many ways are there for six teachers to each choose two children with no one getting a pair of twins?
> 2. How many ways are there to seat n couples around a circular table such that no couple sits next to each other?

I understand how to so this without inclusion-exclusion, but I had no idea how to do using that method. Would someone be able to help me? Thanks in advance, I really appreciate it!

---

edit: After working on the question some, I came up with something. Would someone check to see if my logic is right?

The universe, the amount of arrangements that can be made with n people around a circular table is (2n-1)! . Therefore, following the inclusion-exclusion principles,
$|\cap_{i=1}^n not A_i|$, We can arrange it so each A_i is i couples sitting next to each other.
For example:

A_1 = 1 couple sitting next to each other, which is (2n-1)! - 2!

A_2 = 2 couples sitting next to each other, which is (2n-1)! - 4!

...

A_i = i couples sitting next to each other, which is (2n-1)! - 2i!

Is my logic correct? I appreciate all your help! Thanks in advanced!

Comment: For the first, note that the six teachers can choose the first six children arbitrarily. How many ways are there for six teachers to pick 1 child each? Then how many ways are there for each teacher to pick a second, non-twin child?

Comment: But how do I translate that into specific sets that can be used to perform inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: Oh! I misread your question! I thought you wanted to know how to do this **without** inclusion-exclusion. Sorry.

Comment: No problem! That's what makes this problem so difficult! :p

Comment: Your second problem is analogous to this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78278/using-inclusion-exclusion-on-n-boys-and-n-girls?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

In the first problem there are $\binom{12}{2,2,2,2,2,2}$ ways for the teachers to choose $2$ children each without restriction. There are $6\binom{10}{2,2,2,2,2}$ ways for the first teacher to choose a pair of twins and the other five teachers to choose without restriction, and the same goes for each of the other $5$ teachers, so the first correction in the inclusion-exclusion count is

$$\binom{12}{2,2,2,2,2,2}-\binom61\cdot6\binom{10}{2,2,2,2,2}\;.$$

There are $6\cdot5\binom8{2,2,2,2}$ ways for any given pair of teachers to choose a pair of twins each, and there are $\binom62$ pairs of teachers, so the second correction term results in

$$\binom{12}{2,2,2,2,2,2}-\binom61\cdot6\binom{10}{2,2,2,2,2}+\binom62\cdot6\cdot5\binom8{2,2,2,2}\;.$$

I expect that you can probably finish the inclusion-exclusion argument from here.

Comment: why is there $6*\binom{10}{2,2,2,2,2,2}$ ways for one teacher to choose a pair of twins?

Comment: @Billy: (You have one $2$ too many in the multinomial coefficient.) The teacher can pick any one of the $6$ pairs of twins, and after that the other $5$ teachers are simply selecting $2$ children each from the remaining $10$ children.

Comment: So really its $\binom{6}{1} * \binom{10}{2,2,2,2,2}$ ?

Comment: @Billy: No, because order matters. Look at the next bit, for two teachers picking sets of twins: the first teacher can pick any of the $6$ pairs, and then the second teacher can pick any of the $5$ remaining pairs, so the multiplier is $6\cdot 5$, not $\binom62$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having trouble getting this straight. So Looking at the second bit; You can choose $\binom{6}{2}$ of the teachers to choose their twin. Once the teachers are chosen, the first teacher can choose one of 6 of the twins, then the fifth teacher can choose on of 5 twins. Then, what's left is the $\binom{8}{2,2,2,2}$ twins to be chosen ?

Comment: @Billy: $\binom8{2,2,2,2}$ is the number of ways for the remaining $4$ teachers to choose $2$ children each from the remaining $8$ children, without regard to whether or not any of them takes a pair of twins.

Comment: So besides that last part, am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @Billy: I think so, yes.